# Panorama app better than StreetView

Tags: applications, camera, images

Google's Street View app allows building all-round 360 panoramas, however even with the latest versions, the stiching and exposure quality are really surprisingly poor. Other similar apps have very poor ratings on the Play Store.

Unfortunately, none of the *good* streetview-like images I see for instance on GOogle Maps ([example](https://www.google.at/maps/place/Waldviertelbahn/@48.7649786,14.9839744,3a,77.1y,9.46h,14.06t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipMA-jDSJuwvTler7HdBw4EmdiuRHeSagYdt74_n!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMA-jDSJuwvTler7HdBw4EmdiuRHeSagYdt74_n%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya120.00001-ro-0-fo100!7i15000!8i7500!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sWaldviertelbahn!3m4!1s0x477320e5a6d3dc0f:0xf7160daa72d2496b!8m2!3d48.7649786!4d14.9839744!5m1!1e4)), give any indication what app has been used to make it.

Given the above, I feel this question is relevant, as it does not seem trivial to identify a way in which one can create such high-quality panoramas using an Android phone. Can anybody suggest how such a task can be achieved?

Comment: Unclear/doubtful if "high quality" image capture is achievable with single Android device, see hardware used by Google Street View Trekkers (walking): https://newatlas.com/google-street-view-trekker-upgrade/57728/

Comment: Making good panorama images is difficult and requires a lot of CPU power and RAM and that for just a few images in a small panorama. For a full 360 degree panorama a lot more is required. This will even bring recent high-class phones to it's limit. For my last panorama I created I used a PC and a software called Hugin. Note that also your images have meet certain criteria for a good panorama.

Comment: Hi, please take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are still off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I edited my question.